# "Linking" the count of a few database values to one database value (mySQL)

Tags: mysql, database

I have a question about a database that I am working on for a University Guest lectures. Currently what I have is this:

```
    lectures_available
    +----------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
    |availableSlotID |roomID   |availableDate|availableTime|
    +----------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
    |              1 |       1 | Monday    | 09:00:00  |
    |              2 |       1 | Tuesday   | 07:00:00  |
    |              3 |       1 | Tuesday   | 12:00:00  |
    |              4 |       2 | Wednesday | 11:00:00  |
    |              5 |       2 | Wednesday | 12:00:00  |
    |              6 |       2 | Thursday  | 10:00:00  |
    |              7 |       3 | Tuesday   | 14:00:00  |
    |              8 |       3 | Friday    | 09:00:00  |
    +----------------+---------+-----------+-----------+


    guest_lectures
    +---------+-----------------------+----------+
    | roomID  | lecture               | capacity |
    +---------+-----------------------+----------+
    |       1 | Engineering           |        3 |
    |       2 | Social Science        |        3 |
    |       3 | Archaeology           |        2 |
    |       4 | Biochemistry          |        0 |
    +---------+-----------------------+----------+
```

What I was wondering is if it is possible to link the roomID from lectures_available to the capacity in guest_lectures?

For example right now I have 3 available dates for room 1 (the Engineering lecture room) and its capacity is 3. But after one these 3 gets booked the capacity should change to 2.

A little help would be greatly appreciated! :)
Thank you!

Comment: The `capacity` column seems redundant. You can calculate it using a join between the tables with `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `capacity` column using a `JOIN`.

```
UPDATE guest_lectures AS l
LEFT JOIN lectures_available AS a ON l.room_id = a.room_id
SET l.capacity = IFNULL(COUNT(a.roomID), 0)
```

Comment: No, fine to have two slightly different answers.